# How to deduplicate parquet file too large to fit into memory?

Tags: r, memory, greatest-n-per-group, parquet, apache-arrow

I have a parquet file which is too large to fit into memory.
For simplicity, let's say it has columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, all `int32`.

I want to deduplicate it. So I only want one row per pair of `a`, `b`. When choosing which row to keep for each pair, I want the row with the largest value of `d`, and if there's a tie, the largest value of `e`.

Since I can't fit the whole thing into memory, I can't use `read_parquet`. So instead I've been playing around with `arrow::open_dataset` and `arrow::write_dataset`. Some operations aren't supported without loading the whole dataset into memory. Other approaches throw errors because arrow doesn't support everything.

## MWE

### Generate a sample file

To start, let's generate a large parquet file. I've done this in python just because I'm more confident with Python than R. I'm looking for a solution that works with either R or Python.

My MWE writes data into `~/Downloads`. Change to suit yourself.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = '~/Downloads/test.parquet'
schema = pa.schema({
    'a': pa.uint32(),
    'b': pa.uint32(),
    'c': pa.uint32(),
    'd': pa.uint32(),
    'e': pa.uint32(),
})
rows_per_chunk = 1000000
num_chunks = 1
with pq.ParquetWriter(path, schema) as writer:
    for _ in range(num_chunks):
        data = []
        for k in schema:
            data.append(np.random.randint(0, 100, rows_per_chunk))
        batch = pa.RecordBatch.from_arrays(data, schema=schema)
        writer.write(batch)
```

### What I've tried

```
library(arrow)
library(tidyverse)
library(R.utils)
library(ids)

source_path <- '~/Downloads/test.parquet'
dest_dir <- '~/Downloads/'
```

The following approach works for small files, but not large files, because it loads the whole dataset into memory.

```
read_parquet(source_path) |>
  arrange(a,b,desc(c), desc(d)) |>
  distinct(a, b, .keep_all = TRUE) |>
  write_parquet(file.path(dest_dir, 'simple.parquet'))
```

This next one gives an error.

```
open_dataset(source_path) |>
  arrange(a,b,desc(c), desc(d)) |>
  distinct(a, b, .keep_all = TRUE) |>
  write_dataset(file.path(dest_dir, 'distinct-arrow'))
```

> Error: `distinct()` with `.keep_all = TRUE` not supported in Arrow

This next one also gives an error:

```
open_dataset(source_path) |>
  group_by(a, b) |>
  arrange(desc(c), desc(d)) |>
  filter(n() > 1) |>
  ungroup()
  write_dataset(file.path(dest_dir, 'group-arrange-arrow'))
```

> Error: Filter expression not supported for Arrow Datasets: n() > 1
> Call collect() first to pull data into R.

This next one gives the same error:

```
open_dataset(source_path) |>
  group_by(a, b) |>
  arrange(desc(c), desc(d)) |>
  filter(n() > 1) |>
  write_dataset(file.path(dest_dir, 'group-arrange-arrow'))
```

I was thinking, what if we read the source file as a stream/chunked dataset, and write it out, partitioned into one file per value of `a`. Then each file will be small enough to fit into memory. So we can use the first approach above to deduplicate it. Then we just combine them back into one parquet file. (Or leave them as many small parquet files and get `arrow::open_dataset` to read from many files.)

I tried with this:

```
open_dataset(source_path) |>
  map_batches(function(batch) {
    batch |>
      group_by(a) |>
      write_dataset(
        path = '~/Downloads/batched/',
        basename_template = sprintf("part-%s-{i}.pq", uuid()),
        format = "parquet")
  }, .lazy=TRUE)
```

But got an error:

> Error in UseMethod("as_record_batch") :
> no applicable method for 'as_record_batch' applied to an object of class "NULL"

That's because I didn't call `as_record_batch()`.
But what do we pass to `as_record_batch` when `write_dataset` doesn't return anything?

This code ran without error, but only wrote one file, so it did nothing.
(and I haven't checked if it loads all data into memory first)

```
open_dataset(source_path) |>
  map_batches(function(batch) {
    batch |>
      group_by(a) |>
      as_record_batch()
  }) |>
  write_dataset(
    path = '~/Downloads/batched-2/',
    format = "parquet")
```

I am not looking for a solution involving cloud services (e.g. S3+Athena). Whilst I know how do to that stuff, other people in my team don't. (They're economists, not developers.) So I just want something they can run on their laptop. Python would be a valid solution.